# Sed substitution preserving leading white spaces

Tags: xml, regex, linux, bash, sed

I've been trying to write a sed command to substitute a single word on single line, preserving all the leading white spaces and words.

e.g.
From:

```
<Attr name="x" value="yes"/>
```

To:

```
<Attr name="x" value="no"/>
```

I know that I could just rewrite the entire line but I'd prefer a more elegant way to do it.
Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get stucked?

Comment: `sed` doesn't touch whitespace unless you tell it to. How did you try `sed` that didn't give you the correct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can't parse XML with regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552). Use an XML processing tool. To replace the value for `Attr` nodes where `name` is "x" and `value` is "yes" you can use a tool like `xmlstarlet`:

```
echo '<doc>
  <Attr name="x" value="yes"/>
  <Attr name="y" value="yes"/>
  <Attr name="x" value="maybe"/>
</doc>' |
xmlstarlet ed -u '//Attr[@name="x"][@value="yes"]/@value' -v "no"
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
  <Attr name="x" value="no"/>
  <Attr name="y" value="yes"/>
  <Attr name="x" value="maybe"/>
</doc>
```

Comment: I've not tried it yet, but it seems the best solution and the most flexible! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 4):

I think without adding more specific requirement this simple solution should be fine:

```
sed 's/"yes"/"no"/'
```

Comment: You might want to change it to `s/"yes"/"no"` or `s/\<yes\>/no` so you wouldn't change anything else accidentally.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But I think this wouldn't be an effective solution, as (my fault I didn't explain it) the file contains multiple entries and your solution would change the entire file.

Comment: You can add the target line number before the s.

Answer (score 0):

Lajos' solution will rewrite many occurences of word in file - that's probably not what you want.

Following sed invocation will replace first occurence of "yes" to "no" inside file.xml only in line 3:

```
sed -i 3s/yes/no/ file.xml
```